# ping the FQDN failed but 'short name' works

Tags: networking, dns

I'm on an enterprise LAN (Windows domain and Windows DNS server) and I want to access to another computers on LAN (mostly in https)

On my ubuntu (14.04, fresh install) when I do :

```
ping my_other_server_on_lan -> it works
ping my_other_server_on_lan.mydomain.local -> it doesn't work
```

I tried to change some configuration in /etc/resolv.conf but nothing works

How to ping both myserver and myserver.mydomain.local ?
I don't understand why when I precise the DNS extension

EDIT : I don't need to access to my computer via the fqdn name it is to access to other servers on the LAN

Answer (score 0):

set your computer as if it is in the same domain name:

```
sudo hostname mypc.mydomain.local
```

replace **mypc** with your computer name

Comment: after your solution I'll type hostname--fqdn to see my full hostname. I seems ok but same issue.